# Two symfony projects on one server/domain

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I've created two independent symfony projects and I've moved them to my prod server, for example:

```
project1.example.com [/var/www/project1/web]
project2.example.com [/var/www/project2/web]
```

The problem is that when I open up the second address, then `project1` is fired up. I checked `/var/www/project2/web/app.php` and seems it's properly executed, but for some reason, symfony loaders use `/var/www/project1/` path. Of course the cache folders were cleared.

Any ideas how to diagnose the problem?

**UPDATE**

Apache config files:

[/etc/apache2/apache2.conf](https://pastebin.com/XNBZ5fgZ)
[/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project1.conf + /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project2.conf](https://pastebin.com/PDZT2g96)

**UPDATE 2**

Strange thing, this morning the situation has reversed. Both addresses show site from `project2` now. No config nor project files were modified.

Comment: You might want to check up on [How to Match a Route Based on the Host](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

Comment: What web server are you using in production? Apache? nginx? something else?

Comment: This sounds like a misconfigured webserver

Comment: I'm not sure if this is off-topic for StackOverflow or not, but as it appears to be a SysAdmin issue more than a programming issue, you may have better luck on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @axlj Apache server

Comment: Check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html.  Make sure you have your virtual hosts configured correctly.

Comment: @ACJ I think it doesn't solve my problem. This works fine on dev server (also two subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable Virtual Hosting in Apache.

Take a look at my article on it, it should answer the question:

https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/apache-httpd-virtualhost-config/

If you need further help with that, you can always post another question. I use this all the time.

---

EDIT #2 - based on Apache 2 conf:

Suggest you combine SSL and HTTP VirtualHost ports like so, and also just have a single `Directory` directive to the web folder. There are other redundancies in the conf file. Please read some documents first about the Apache config files before asking questions.

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /var/www/project1/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

For the Project2 problem, have you checked the logs in $APACHE_LOG_DIR to see what they show? I think logs are usually in `/var/log`; there's probably an `httpd` subdirectory with the httpd logs. You need to make sure there is an incoming GET request for `project1.example.com.pl`. If not, you'll need to check all your `hosts` files to see they are setup correctly.

Comment: @axlj I mentioned that www root for project2 is fired correctly, so I guess the apache conf is not a problem

Comment: Can you please show your Apache config, or post it on pastebin. This does exactly sound like a configuration issue. Also, i presume you've updated your respective `hosts` files?

Comment: You only posted part of the config files. Was there a limit on Pastebin?

Comment: Also, I see no `<VirtualHost *:80>` sections whatsoever. So i guess you didn't read my article and understand it!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't notice that tags from the conf files was not copied. Links are updated. Do you want some other config files?